# basic_ofstream<unsigned char> in gcc fails

Tags: c++, gcc

I have listed below some working code

```
ofstream of("/home/joe/test.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
of.write((char*)&dat[0],dat.size());
```

but the code below produces no output

```
basic_ofstream<unsigned char> of("/home/joe/test.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
of.write(&dat[0],dat.size());
```

I tried with gcc 4.9 on linux. Note that there is no compilation warning or error.

Answer (score 2):

This is not working:

```
basic_ofstream<unsigned char> of("/tmp/test2.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
of.write(&dat[0],dat.size());
```

But this is working:

```
basic_ofstream<char> of("/tmp/test3.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
 of.write((char*)&dat[0],dat.size());
```

The implementation is under no obligation to supply an instantiation of `std::char_traits<unsigned char>`, and those that do have incompatible instantiations. It might work with a particular compiler, but it's not required.

Comment: I presume I might land up with similar issues with basic_string<unsigned char> as well for the same reasons.

Comment: Today, GCC supports unsigned char, but Clang still does not: https://godbolt.org/g/js71QF